# Random post order - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On single posts i display other posts like this outside the loop

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=200&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
```

Trying adding

```
query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand');
```

But however i try it don't do it in random order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that i didn't put it first in get_posts like

```
$posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=200&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) :  
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> 
<?php 
endforeach; 

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You can see the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts